# Not able to Sign Up for a retail website by using Selenium Webdriver even though there is no error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to sign up to Nordstrom site via Selenium with C#. The code executes correctly but for some reason the sign up does not happen. After sign up the Nordstrom site on the top right corner should say account instead of Login/Sign Up. There is no error whatsever but it just does not sign up. Is there something wrong with the way Create Account button is clicked?

Here's the code

```
using NordstromRack.UI_Elements;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace NordstromRack
{
    class EntryPoint
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String parentHandle = Driver.driver.CurrentWindowHandle; // get the current window handle
            EmailSignUp signup = new EmailSignUp();
            Driver.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.nordstromrack.com/");
            Driver.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            signup.SignUpLink.Click();

            foreach (String winHandle in Driver.driver.WindowHandles)
            {
                Driver.driver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandle);
            }
            //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
            //wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(signup.EmailInput));

            signup.EmailInput.Click();
            signup.EmailInput.SendKeys(Config.Credentials.Valid.BaseEmail);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            signup.Password.Click();
            signup.Password.SendKeys(Config.Credentials.Valid.Password);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Actions action = new Actions(Driver.driver);
            action.MoveToElement(signup.CreateAccount).Click().Perform();
            Console.WriteLine("Signup Successful");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            //Driver.driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the class for identifying elements

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace NordstromRack.UI_Elements
{
    public class EmailSignUp
    {
        public EmailSignUp()
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(Driver.driver, this);
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input.form-label__input.form-label__input--password")]
        public IWebElement Password { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input.form-label__input.form-label__input--email")]
        public IWebElement EmailInput { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "secondary-nav__link")]
        public IWebElement SignUpLink { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "button.cta-button.cta-button--nordstromrack")]
        public IWebElement CreateAccount { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Here is Driver Class

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace NordstromRack
{
    public static class Driver
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all this

```
signup.Password.SendKeys(Config.Credentials.Valid.Password);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Actions action = new Actions(Driver.driver);
action.MoveToElement(signup.CreateAccount).Click().Perform()
```

Try this.Not required to click on "Create Account" button.

```
signup.Password.SendKeys(Config.Credentials.Valid.Password);
signup.Password.Submit();
```

Comment: Already did! I have posted another question if you can help me with that, Same project but unable to locate an element that would help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
signup.CreateAccount.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

In place of

```
Actions action = new Actions(Driver.driver);
action.MoveToElement(signup.CreateAccount).Click().Perform();
```

Note you will need to add `Keys` to your selenium imports.

?